# Python Request save cookie response in browser

Tags: django, cookies, request

i have a django web app that use request to post to my gofiber api in response it get a session cookie i need that session cookie in my js fetch in the frontend but my request does not set the cookie in the browser

```
def login(request):


    email = ""
    password = ""

    if request.method == 'POST':

        session = requests.Session()
        email = request.POST['email_test']
        password = request.POST['password']
        email = "test@test.com"
        password = "Test"
        url = "http://localhost:8006/auth/login"

        myobj = {'email': email, "password": password}
        x = session.post(url, json=myobj)

        if x.status_code == 200:
            print(x.cookies)
            session_cookies = dict(x.cookies)
            request.session['session_id'] = session_cookies            
            print("Session cookies: " + str(session_cookies))
            print(session_cookies)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

        return HttpResponse("Login failed")

    return render(request, "webadmin/login.html", {
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    })
```

```
print(x.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie kronborg_id=3f6be328-c4e1-4faf-a26b-7b04bc48d006 for localhost.local/>]>
print(session_cookies)
{'kronborg_id': '3f6be328-c4e1-4faf-a26b-7b04bc48d006'}
```